# ¿Por qué no funciona esta condición? jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Por qué no funciona esta función? Quiero que cuando el ancho de la ventana sea igual o menor de 425px le añada ese estilo al div `#video-container`

```js
if ($(window).width() <= 425){
  $('#video-container').css({'margin-bottom': '-250px !important'});  
}
```

```css
.no-padding{
 padding:0px !important;
}
.no-margin{
 margin:0px !important;
}
#video-container{
 height:85vh;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.video{
 width: 100%;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="no-margin no-padding">
  <section class="row no-padding no-margin">
     <div id="video-container" class="row no-margin no-padding">
         <video autoplay loop muted>
           <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
         </video>
      </div>
                   ...
                 Código HTML
                   ...
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes enseñar un código reproducible? Tal y como lo tienes ahora no le veo ningún fallo a simple vista.

Comment: actualizado el op

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El operador `=<` debe ser `<=`

Y la syntaxis del [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) esta mal

```
if ($(window).width() <= 425){

  $('#video-container').css({'margin-top': '250px'});  
}
```

Te recomiendo que uses [window.innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth)

[Ver demo](http://output.jsbin.com/gufepewuki)

*Mi primera respuesta se debe antes de las ediciones: [Enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/34999/3)*

---

**Edit según las ediciones y comentarios:**

Te dejo un demo donde uso solo `css` con `media query`... y según las ediciones te he corregido también el `css`...

[Ver demo 2](http://output.jsbin.com/sofuna)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {  
  #video-container{
      top: -250px;
  }
}
```

Un ejemplo más como realizar en `JS/jQuery` un comportamiento igual al `CSS media query` con el evento [.resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) de `jQuery`:

[Ver demo 3](http://output.jsbin.com/hikaza)

```
$(function(){

    $(window).resize(function(){

        if (window.innerWidth <= 425){

            $('#video-container').css({'top': '-250px'});  

        } else {

          $('#video-container').css({'top': 'initial'});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yup!! Eso mismo.

Comment: Cambiado en el op y tampoco funciona

Comment: Tampoco funciona con esa sintaxis del css...

Comment: @PavloB. - Porque editas cada vez tu pregunta... si lo editas no tiene sentido mi respuesta para otros

Comment: Para mantenerlo actualizado ya que el error persiste, pero tienes razón que no servirá para los otros que puedan tener el mismo problema... Ahora, no sé como usar el window.innerWidth pero creo qu eno es problema del `$(window).width();` ya que al poner un `alert($(window).width()` dentro del `if` cuando la ventana tiene menos de 425px y recargo salta el alert con el numero correspondiente al ancho. sin embargo no funciona "a tiempo real" porque tengo que recargar para que haga efecto...

Comment: @PavloB. y porque no usas `@media` query en css? Te voy a dar un ejemplo... un segundo

Comment: @PavloB. - Mira ahora si te sirve... luego cuando tenga más tiempo te dare un ejemplo con js

Comment: Así sí que funciona, gracias, aunque sigo sin entender por qué no funciona con jquery pero gracias, me sirve con css =)

Comment: @PavloB. - Te he dejado otro ejemplo con JS

Comment: @PavloB. si puedes realizar cosas con CSS, te será mucho más rápido, tanto a la hora de escribir el código, como para el navegador al renderizar y no tener que cargar javascript